# Text for post buttons is no longer visible (in most cases) in iOS app on iPad OS 13.1

Tags: bug, design, ios-app

> [image]

It seems there is an issue with font size.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: Unknown (iPad 7,3)
- OS Version: Version 13.1 (Build 17A844)