# Share menu hangs iOS app

Tags: bug, ios-app, share-this

The Share menu in iOS 13 got a redesign, and the Stack Exchange iOS app is no longer compatible with it. I can still use it to copy the link, but when I try close the menu, it remains stuck.
Opening another app and then returning automatically dismisses the menu, but then I can't use the back button anymore to return to the question list. (I'm still able to refresh the page, so it's a navigation issue.)

[image]

<sub>Ironically, I discovered this bug while trying to mark [this bug report about the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333779/295232) as a duplicate; in the app, the quickest way to do that is to use the Share menu to copy the link to the original question to the clipboard...</sub>

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 13.1 (Build 17A844)

Comment: Unfortunately, [the app development is currently frozen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/ios-app/info) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later iOS versions (14, 15, I'm not really sure of the exact version) have solved this problem. The menu can be closed as it used to be, and all share options work like they used to do before.

Comment: OMG, the app is still alive???

Comment: If you had it installed before it was delisted, yes. I fear I'll have to do without it when I get a new iPhone, even when I restore it from a backup.

Comment: Huh. So save your old iPhone just for the SE app. ;)

Comment: That, or write an app which monitors my inbox and sends push messages. The app works only slightly better than the responsive website these days.

Comment: That's still no less than real miracle, and only super dev like Brian could pull such thing off. Android app was **never** better than the web version, always full of bugs, even when working. I understand why Kasra could never fix it, and feel bad for him, it's 100% SE fault for not simply hiring another android dev. And sadly it went below the radar, and now water under the bridge, but personally one of my key reasons to dislike SE (as a company, its management) , to this day.

Answer (score 9):

You can avoid having the app freeze at all while still getting your share link.

The trick is:

1. Tap on “mail” and copy the link from there.
2. Delete the email draft, do not try to send it else it will lock up.
3. Then swipe the share menu down (do **not** use the close button).

If you do end up having the app freeze you can unfreeze it by opening a draft. I always have at least one draft at the bottom of the app. You just need to keep leaving and coming back to app to actually get there.